# Vim autocommand trigger on opening "nothing"

Tags: vim, autocmd

I want vim to open up the :Explorer when no file is opened or created. Eg. when I call `vim` without any options.

calling `vim newfile.txt` should still behave the normal way though.

How would I go about doing this? I can't seem to find the correct `autocmd` for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this for vim invocation only, the best way is to use `argc()`:

```
autocmd VimEnter * :if argc() is 0 | Explore | endif
```

`argc()` function returns a number of filenames specified on command-line when vim was invoked unless something modified arguments list, more information at `:h argc()`.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself:

```
"open to Explorer when no file is opened
function! TabIsEmpty()
    " Remember which window we're in at the moment
    let initial_win_num = winnr()

    let win_count = 0
    " Add the length of the file name on to count:
    " this will be 0 if there is no file name
    windo let win_count += len(expand('%'))

    " Go back to the initial window
    exe initial_win_num . "wincmd w"

    " Check count
    if win_count == 0
        " Tab page is empty
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    endif
endfunction

" Test it like this:
" echo TabIsEmpty()

function! OpenExplorer()
    if (TabIsEmpty())
        :Explore
    end  
endfunction
```

The greatest part of this code was taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025558/check-if-current-tab-is-empty-in-vim).